# Why is ng-click not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick

Why on earth wont this simple ng-click example work? I've been using angular for months in production, but this plunker is baffling me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9Rp5JD?p=preview

If you notice, the ng-show  properties are working... why isn't the click? It always alerts the default and not the angular click.

```
<div ng-show="showTest" ng-click="alert('angular click')" onclick="alert('default click')">Default or angular click?</div>
<div ng-show="dontShowMeIsNotDefinedSoIWontShow" >Not showing me, I know angular is working!</div>
```

there's no isolated scope, no directive at all... just a div. You can remove the onclick.... the other alert never fires. I'm sure whatever the problem is, I've become too myopic to find it.

the rest of the boring config:

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

var app = angular.module('plunker', [
    'plunker'
]);



app.config( function( ) {
        'use strict';
});



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var that = this;

  $scope.showTest = true;

});
```

the whole html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

<br/><br/>

<div ng-show="showTest" ng-click="alert('angular click')" onclick="alert('default click')">Default or angular click?</div>
<div ng-show="dontShowMeIsNotDefinedSoIWontShow" >Not showing me, I know angular is working!</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Include all of the relevant code **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. For web stuff, you can use Stack Snippets to demonstrate *exactly* what you're running into.

Comment: that's pretty much all the code, unless you want to see my empty angular config, which I'm adding now.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. But again: Why not a Stack Snippet? Don't tell, *show*.

Comment: Stack overflow pertains to tools used by developers, and in my mind this applies to plunker and my question is directly related to it.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that questions have to be self-contained. Your question isn't just for you, now; it's for others, later. If plunker disappears (which it easily could), the question must make sense *without* it. A Stack Snippet ensures that the question is self-contained (but with your edit, provided that's all the code needed, it's self-contained even without a Stack Snippet -- an SS would just make it easier for people to help you, which is surely a goal?).

Comment: eh this snippet thing looks nice. so much fragmentation in this arena now. jsfiddle, plnkr, snippet

Comment: But just the one that's local here. :-) (Sadly not yet up to snuff vs. jsfiddle, jsbin, etc., but hopefully that will change.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular's expressions do not use the `eval` function so unless you have defined a function named `alert` in your scope chain somewhere it will not execute.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context
>
> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.
>
> Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called
>   from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

So you would have to define such a function on your scope:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$window) { 
  var that = this;

  $scope.showTest = true;
  $scope.alert = function() {
    $window.alert('angular click');
  };
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('plunker', []);

var app = angular.module('plunker', [
    'plunker'
]);

app.config( function( ) {
        'use strict';
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$window) { 
  var that = this;

  $scope.showTest = true;
  $scope.alert = function(text){
     $window.alert(text);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-show="showTest" ng-click="alert('angular click')" onclick="alert('default click')">Default or angular click?</div>
<div ng-show="dontShowMeIsNotDefinedSoIWontShow" >Not showing me, I know angular is working!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Added an `alert` attribute to your controller definition:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var that = this;

  $scope.showTest = true;

  $scope.alert = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  };
});
```

I think the issue is that the `ng-click` directive will automatically interpret whatever you put inside in the scope of the controller object.  So if the controller doesn't have an `alert` attribute, nothing happens.

Comment: ah, duh, had a feeling i just overlooked something basic like that, i.e. scope. the only reason I'm conducting these silly tests is in a persuit of custom elements (web widgets) so I was already frustrated...

Comment: @FlavorScape I've lost count of the number of times I've lost mornings and afternoons to "something basic".  Hopefully this helps?