# Controller without $scope

Tags: angularjs

I just come across some code where no $scope was there in the controller.

### Here is the code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrlCarLists as cars">
<button ng-click="cars.showCars()">
Cars
</button>

<button ng-click="alert(cars.data)">
Test
</button>
</div>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("ctrlCarLists", function () {

this.data = 'hello';
this.showCars = function () {
    alert("Ford, Toyata, Mercedes");
    };
});
```

The above code is running, but `this.data` is not accessible...why? showCars() is accessible when the button is clicked. Why isn't `this.data` is not accessible?

What should be called when we declare any variable or function inside controller with the `this` keyword? Will it behave like a static property or function of a class?

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/z5wkzc0g/

Comment: take a look into this article https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: in Angular 2 the $scope will be gone, so its good to train your brain to use controller as

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use alert from ng-click of a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907383/use-alert-from-ng-click-of-a-directive)

Comment: I call mine vm.showCars (var vm = this;) its easy for me to distinguish that it has something to do with a viewModel rather then just this. or scope

Comment: It's not `cars.data` that is inaccessible. Its `alert`.

Comment: if possible please discuss with sample code that where i made the mistake ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z5wkzc0g/1/

Comment: if data would be part of $scope then do i need to declare a function alert inside controller to show data value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ng-click** requires an expression ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)).

`alert(cars.data)`

is not an expression that angularJS can compile (it doesn't know what **alert** refers to) thus it should be replaced with

```
ng-click="cars.data()"
```

because `cars.data()` is an expression it can compile.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/z5wkzc0g/7/)

Or, alternatively

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/z5wkzc0g/11/)

where we could have this:

```
this.alert = function (text) {
    alert(text);
}
```

Comment: you said `alert()` is not expression but alert is js function....angular does not aware about any js in built function?

Comment: @Mou Yes, you can think of AngularJS *in the DOM* not understanding regular JavaScript code that is not on the scope. So for example `var myVariable` cannot be used while `$rootScope.myVariable`, `$scope.myVariable` and `cars.myVariable` can.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-controller="ctrlCarLists as cars"
```

"cars" is referring to your controller, and "this" is refering to your controller as well.

```
ng-click="cars.showCars()"
```

When this function is triggered, it will refer to "showCars()" function in your controller.

Comment: i refer the data as same way `<button ng-click="alert(cars.data)">` then why data is not getting accessible?

Comment: because alert have been treated as a function name in the controller

Answer (score 1):

As Yury Tarabanko has explained in his comment, alert function is not found, reason is:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context
>
> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.
>
> Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called
>   from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

Source:

[Why is ng-click not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536484/why-is-ng-click-not-working)